# AttributeError:__exit__ on python 3.4

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, with-statement, mysql-connector-python

Original Code:

```
import sys
import os
import latexmake

import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='oilwell',host='localhost',database='sqlpush1')

with conn:
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
mycursor=execute("SELECT DATE,oil,gas,oilprice,gasprice,totrev FROM results WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2027-12-01'")
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
a.write("\\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{booktabs}\n\n\\usepackage{siunitx}\r \n\
\r\n\\begin{document}\r\n\\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format = 5.2]} \\\\ \\toprule\r")
a.write("Date & Oil & Gas & Oil price & Gas price & Total Revenue \\\\ \\midrule \r")
for row in rows:
    a = open("testtest.tex", "w")
    a.write("" + str(row[0]) + " & " + str(row[1]) + " & " + str(row[2]) + " & " + str(row[3]) + " & " + str(row[4]) + " & " + str(row[5]) + " \\\\ \r")

    a.write("\\bottomrule \\end{tabular}\r\\end{document}")
    a.close
print (os.path.getsize("testtest.tex"))
os.system('latexmk.py -q testtest.tex')
mycursor.close()
conn.close()
a.close()
```

After run by IDLE, and red error pop up like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cheng XXXX\Desktop\tabletest.py", line 8, in <module>
    with conn:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

I checked the file and cannot file mistake, need help.

Comment: `conn` is not a context manager, it is `with` that tries to store `conn.__exit__` to call when the context exits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you be more specific? How can I solve this case? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql.connector` connection as a context manager. It may work with other MySQL libraries, but not this one.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the connection as a context manager:

```
with conn:
```

This object doesn't implement the necessary methods to be used like that; it is not a context manager, as it is missing (at least) the [`__exit__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

If you are reading a tutorial or documentation that uses a *different* MySQL library, be aware that this feature may be supported by *some* libraries, just not this one. The [MySQLdb project](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1) does support it, for example.

For your *specific* case, you don't even need to use the `with conn:` line at all; you are not making any changes to the database, no commit is required anywhere. You can safely remove the `with conn:` line (unindent everything under it one step). Otherwise you can replace the context manager with a manual `conn.commit()` elsewhere.

Alternatively, you can create your own context manager for this use-case, using the [`@contextlib.contextmanager()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def manage_transaction(conn, *args, **kw):
    exc = False
    try:
        try:
            conn.start_transaction(*args, **kw)
            yield conn.cursor()
        except:
            exc = True
            conn.rollback()
    finally:
        if not exc:
            conn.commit()
```

and use this as:

```
with manage_transaction(conn) as cursor:
    # do things, including creating extra cursors
```

where you can pass in extra arguments for the [`connection.start_transaction()` call](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-start-transaction.html).

Comment: My python version is 3.4, which MySQLdb does not support it. So, there is no way to execute this script with MySQL Connector/Python? Newbie for python, thank a lot for your time.

Comment: @ChengZhang: you can, just not use that one feature. You can use my alternative, or remove the `with conn:` line (unindent the rest), and add an explicit `conn.commit()` at the end instead.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters You mean delete "with conn" and put "conn.commit()" at the very end?

Comment: @ChengZhang: yes. But the `conn.commit()` is not even needed; you never make any changes *to* commit.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters The new error come out, "NameError: name 'a' is not defined", but under "wiht conn", there is no such an issue.

Comment: @ChengZhang: that's because the problem you had before was just the first error you hit. Look carefully at your code. You assign `a` way later than you try to use it; you cannot use `a.write()` before you *create* the open file object with `a = open(...)`.

Comment: @ChengZhang: You may want to bring back your problems to small manageable bite sizes here. Make the SQL query work first. Then add the file processing in later. Make sure you can make the file processing work in isolation first and understand how that works. Etc.

Comment: @ChengZhang: Otherwise you'll keep running into problems you don't necessarily understand and know how to fix.

Comment: I will take the advises from you. Thanks a lot.